# Problems loading and displaying a csv file from Software Carpentry to Jupyterlab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

**Brief Summary**:
I have recently been going through lessons on a website called Software Carpentry, which provides basic learning for the UNIX shell, Python, and R. I have recently been going through one of their workshops called "Plotting and Programming with Python", where I'm supposed to learn how to use the panda library to analyze and plot data on the GDP of different countries. However, when I got to the module called reading tabular data, I imported panda, did the panda.read_csv to load the file, then displayed it with print. When I did this, it claimed that the file or directory that I specified in the call did not exist.

**Here are the links as reference to what I am working on**:

The files that I was supposed to download, called python-novice-gapminder-data.zip, are in this link: http://swcarpentry.github.io/python-novice-gapminder/setup.html

The part of the workshop that I am working on is here: http://swcarpentry.github.io/python-novice-gapminder/07-reading-tabular/index.html

**Description of my process**
When I first downloaded the gapminder zip file in the link above, I went to my downloads folder, took the folder called 'data' out of the zip folder, renamed it 'data-plotting' and moved it to my Desktop(relative path is OneDrive/Desktop/data-plotting).This data plotting folder had all of the GDP csv files that I needed for this lesson. I then opened up a new notebook in Jupyter lab, making sure that I opened it up and saved it in my data-plotting folder. Then I did the following code:

`import panda as pd`

`data = pd.read_csv('data-plotting/gapminder_gdp_oceania.csv')`

`print(data)`

I then proceeded to get a FileNotFoundError, stating that:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data-plotting/gapminder_gdp_oceania.csv'

I'm not sure what I did wrong here, do any of you have any ideas for troubleshooting? In my Gitbash, it did in fact confirm that the data-plotting directory was in Desktop, and that gapminder_gdp_oceania.csv was in data-plotting. Thank you.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Assuming Linux/Mac, What happens when within the same notebook you execute `!pwd` and `!ls` in the same cell? (I think for Windows that would be `!dir` instead of `!ls`). What is the file browser in JupyterLab showing?

Comment: I am using Windows, and I'll try both commands. When I typed !pwd and !ls into the notebook I got the error: 'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. As for the Jupyter Lab file browser, it says that my current notebook is  in ../Desktop/data-plotting.

Comment: What about `!dir`? As I mentioned the other two commands were for Linux/Mac (which I do recommend trying out when taking a course on UNIX shell ;) )

Comment: Okay I fixed it, rather than doing the panda command ```data = pd.read_csv('data-plotting/gapminder_gdp_oceania.csv')
print(data)``` I just removed the directory name from the argument and it displayed the data just fine. Thanks for the help! And I did try out !dir, and it did show me the file info for my directory!